# Hiding the keyboard when user hit the return key on keyboard

Tags: android, key

First, I don't know what's the key code for the <kbd>Return</kbd> key or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> the one that has a line on the Android keyboard.

Secondly I have multiple edittext fields on the screen and I want each one to resign the keyboard when the user hit that <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

```
    imm= (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

   public void onClick(View v) {
     int flag;
     flag=v.getId();
     // keycode for return
     if(v.getId()==XX) {
         imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(YYY.getWindowToken(), 0);

     }
```

`XX` is the keycode for that <kbd>Return</kbd> key and `YYY` is what I should fill in. I would like `YYY` generic  that's applying to all the edittext fields in the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are trying to handle this in an `onClick` method. The right way, I think, is to call [`setOnKeyListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html) for each EditText view and in your [`OnKeyListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html), you can do this:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode = KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        // non-null only for enter key
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

A single instance of `OnKeyListener` can be used for all EditText views (any view at all, actually) where you want this behavior.